# Configuring Default Content for Editable Email Notification Jenkins

Tags: html, email, jenkins

I have Jenkins configured on my local to run tests. I am using Editable E-mail notification to send email to a recipient list, an html report as the email body and the same html report attached to the mail as well.

I have written an ANT task for creating the html by converting the .jtl file into html using an xsl.(for performance testing)

It works fine when I set Default Content of the email in Jenkins to:-

```
Content Type : HTML(text/html)

Default Content : ${FILE, path="localpath/Test.html"}
```

I am able to see the html content in the mail body, but I have to send the report in such a way that BUILD_NUMBER gets appended to my Test.html like **Test_BUILD_NUMBER.html** just to keep track of all the previous html result as well and not to overwrite the existing result html. So I tried to use:-

```
Content Type : HTML(text/html)

Default Content : ${FILE, path="localpath/Test_${ENV, var="BUILD_NUMBER"}.html"}
```

**My problem is:**
Now I am not able to see any html content in the mail and only the String similar to 'Default Content' mentioned above is seen in the mail body:-
`Mail body in the mail: ${FILE, path="localpath/Test_67}.html"}(It shows the build number though)`

However when I pass the same html path as attachment in the mail than its getting attached as attachment in the mail properly. This works for the attachment:-
`Attachements: localpath/Test_${ENV, var="BUILD_NUMBER"}.html`

**What will be the proper syntax to set the Default Content in the mail for the problem mentioned above?**

Comment: To start with, try escaping the nested quotes, try `\"`

Comment: Slav- I tried that but now its giving error as ERROR: File '<localPath>/<Filename>_26.html' does not exist. but attachment is still there. I tried checking if time taken by file to be created before adding it as <mailContent>is causing problem, but that is not the case as well.